# Orbeon - Extremely slow xml big data import [load and save]

Tags: xml, xpath, xhtml, orbeon, xforms

I'm creating a form with an xml file import functionality. I want to iterate the xml file imported to obtain the corresponding rows of a grid table.
Each row is made up by a set of different input text (so for example, each row has ten input text components) that are created dinamically with the corresponding value from the xml file imported.

The structure of the xml file is the following:

```
<nodeList>
    <node>
        <value1>test</value1>
        <value2>test</value2>
        <value3>test</value3>
        <value4>test</value4>
        <value5>test</value5>
        <value6>test</value6>
        <value7>test</value7>
        <value8>test</value8>
        <value9>test</value9>
        <value10>test</value10>
    </node>
    ...
    (with N nodes)
</nodeList>
```

---

So my task is to create N rows by these N nodes, dinamically.

Firstly I achieve this task with the xforms upload component and an action with iterate attribute to loop through the xml file nodes loaded in a separate instance: each iteration inserted a row in a repeated-grid (with a template) and then did a set of setvalue to load the values into each input text component of each row. Here the logic:

```
<xf:instance id="upload">
    <serialized mediatype="application/xml" filename=""/>
</xf:instance>
<xf:bind ref="instance('upload')" type="xs:base64Binary"/>
<xf:submission id="upload-submission" ref="instance('upload')" validate="false"
               relevant="false"
               method="post"
               replace="none"
               resource="echo:"/>
<xf:action id="upload-binding">

    <!-- Request actions -->
    <xf:action event="xforms-submit" ev:observer="upload-submission">
        <!-- Copy over to read-write request instance -->
        <xf:insert ref="instance('fr-service-response-instance')"
                   origin="saxon:parse(saxon:base64Binary-to-string(xs:base64Binary(instance('upload')), 'UTF-8'))"/>
    </xf:action>
    <xf:action event="xforms-submit-done" ev:observer="upload-submission">
        <xf:delete ref="instance('fr-form-instance')//nodes-iteration"/>
        <xf:action iterate="instance('fr-service-response-instance')//*:node">
            <xf:insert context="instance('fr-form-instance')//nodes" ref="*"
                       origin="instance('nodes-template')"/>
            <xf:setvalue ref="instance('fr-form-instance')//nodes-iteration[last()]/value1"
                         value="context()//*:value1"/>
            <xf:setvalue ref="instance('fr-form-instance')//nodes-iteration[last()]/value2"
                         value="context()//*:value2"/>
            <xf:setvalue ref="instance('fr-form-instance')//nodes-iteration[last()]/value3"
                         value="context()//*:value3"/>
            ...
            (with N xf:setvalue)                         
        </xf:action>
    </xf:action>
</xf:action>

.......

<xf:upload id="upload-div" ref="instance('upload')">
    <xf:filename ref="@filename"/>
    <xf:mediatype ref="@mediatype"/>
    <xf:send event="xxforms-upload-done" submission="upload-submission"/>
</xf:upload>
```

---

This solution was good but very slow, so I tried with the xforms repeat component and inserting the whole xml file nodes directly into the instance associated with the repeat component.

This solution instead was faster, but with 5000 nodes our form loading components was very slow too (1 minute and 42 seconds).

With 5000 nodes, only the save action spends 7 minutes and 45 seconds to finish.

The loading page of a form with these 5000 nodes saved yet spends 2 minutes and 26 seconds to finish.

I need to reduce these times.
I also try with different environments (with better hardware) or configurations (I try to disable the validations system too), but the times are almost the same.

---

Edited for additional information:

I revert the code to this old solution and give it a try: the single insert works but not the `setvalue set`.
Should I replace just the `last()` index with `current()` for each `setvalue ref` ?

```
<xf:setvalue ref="instance('fr-form-instance')//nodes-iteration[current()]/value1" value="context()//*:value1"/>
```

If so it still doesn't work and spends too much time to finish.

Instead have you some suggestions for the `xf:repeat` component ? Here our last solution:

```
<xf:bind ref="instance('fr-form-instance')/nodes-iteration//*:node">
    <xf:bind id="value1-bind" ref="./*:value1" required="true()"/>
    <xf:bind id="value2-bind" ref="./*:value2" required="true()"/>
    <xf:bind id="value3-bind" ref="./*:value3" type="xs:date" required="true()"/>
    <xf:bind id="value4-bind" ref="./*:value4" required="true()"/>
    <xf:bind id="value5-bind" ref="./*:value5" />
    <xf:bind id="value6-bind" ref="./*:value6" required="true()"/>
    <xf:bind id="value7-bind" ref="./*:value7" required="true()"/>
    <xf:bind id="value8-bind" ref="./*:value8" required="true()"/>
    <xf:bind id="value9-bind" ref="./*:value9" required="true()"/>
    <xf:bind id="value10-bind" ref="./*:value10" required="true()"/>
</xf:bind>      

...

<xf:instance id="node-item" >
    <data>
        <node>
            <value1/>
            <value2/>
            <value3/>
            <value4/>
            <value5/>
            <value6/>
            <value7/>
            <value8/>
            <value9/>
            <value10/>
        </node>             
    </data>
</xf:instance>  
<xf:instance id="upload" >
    <serialized mediatype="application/xml" filename=""/>
</xf:instance>
<xf:bind ref="instance('upload')" type="xs:base64Binary"/>
<xf:submission id="upload-submission" ref="instance('upload')" validate="false"
               relevant="false"
               method="post"
               replace="none"
               resource="echo:"/>          
<!-- Request actions -->
<xf:action event="xforms-submit-done" ev:observer="upload-submission">      
    <!-- Copy over to read-write request instance -->           
    <xf:insert ref="instance('fr-form-instance')/nodes-iteration/data"
               origin="saxon:parse(saxon:base64Binary-to-string(xs:base64Binary(instance('upload')), 'UTF-8'))"/>                                                  
</xf:action>

...

<fr:section id="nodes-iteration-control" bind="nodes-iteration-bind">
    <xf:label ref="$form-resources/nodes-iteration/label"/>
    <xh:table class="fr-grid fr-grid-4 fr-grid-nodes table table-bordered table-condensed fr-repeat fr-repeat-multiple-rows">
    <xh:thead class="fr-grid-head">
        <xh:tr class="fr-grid-tr">
            <xh:th class="fr-grid-th xforms-table-header">
                <xf:trigger id="addNew-control" bind="addNew-bind">
                    <xf:label>Aggiungi Nuovo</xf:label>
                    <xf:action event="DOMActivate">
                        <xf:insert ref="instance('fr-form-instance')//*:node" at="last()" position="after" origin="instance('node-item')//*:node"/>                             
                    </xf:action>
                    <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/addNew/hint"/>
                    <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                </xf:trigger>                           
            </xh:th>
        </xh:tr>                    
    </xh:thead>             
    <xh:tbody class="fr-grid-body">
        <xf:repeat id="node-repeats" ref="instance('fr-form-instance')/nodes-iteration//*:node" >
            <xh:tr class="fr-grid-tr can-insert-above can-insert-below xforms-repeat-selected-item-1">
                <xh:td class="fr-grid-td">                              
                    <xf:var name="countRow" value="position()"/>
                    <xf:trigger id="removeItem-control" bind="removeItem-bind">
                        <xf:label>X</xf:label>
                        <xf:action event="DOMActivate" if="$countRow = 1">
                            <xf:setvalue ref="instance('fr-form-instance')/nodes-iteration//*:node[$countRow]/*:value1" value="''"/>
                            <xf:setvalue ref="instance('fr-form-instance')/nodes-iteration//*:node[$countRow]/*:value2" value="''"/>
                            <xf:setvalue ref="instance('fr-form-instance')/nodes-iteration//*:node[$countRow]/*:value3" value="''"/>
                            <xf:setvalue ref="instance('fr-form-instance')/nodes-iteration//*:node[$countRow]/*:value4" value="''"/>
                            <xf:setvalue ref="instance('fr-form-instance')/nodes-iteration//*:node[$countRow]/*:value5" value="''"/>
                            <xf:setvalue ref="instance('fr-form-instance')/nodes-iteration//*:node[$countRow]/*:value6" value="''"/>
                            <xf:setvalue ref="instance('fr-form-instance')/nodes-iteration//*:node[$countRow]/*:value7" value="''"/>
                            <xf:setvalue ref="instance('fr-form-instance')/nodes-iteration//*:node[$countRow]/*:value8" value="''"/>
                            <xf:setvalue ref="instance('fr-form-instance')/nodes-iteration//*:node[$countRow]/*:value9" value="''"/>
                            <xf:setvalue ref="instance('fr-form-instance')/nodes-iteration//*:node[$countRow]/*:value10" value="''"/>
                        </xf:action>                                        
                        <xf:action event="DOMActivate" if="$countRow != 1">
                            <xf:delete ref="instance('fr-form-instance')/nodes-iteration//*:node" at="index('node-repeats')"/>
                        </xf:action>                                        
                        <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/removeItem/hint"/>
                        <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                    </xf:trigger>                                   
                    <xf:input id="nodeNumber-control" ref="$countRow">
                        <xf:label ref="$form-resources/nodeNumber/label"/>
                        <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/nodeNumber/hint"/>
                        <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                    </xf:input>
                </xh:td>
                <xh:td class="fr-grid-td">
                    <xf:input id="value1-control" bind="value1-bind">
                        <xf:label ref="$form-resources/value1/label"/>
                        <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/value1/hint"/>
                        <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                    </xf:input>
                </xh:td>
                <xh:td class="fr-grid-td">
                    <xf:input id="value2-control" bind="value2-bind">
                        <xf:label ref="$form-resources/value2/label"/>
                        <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/value2/hint"/>
                        <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                    </xf:input>
                </xh:td>
                <xh:td class="fr-grid-td">
                    <xf:input id="value3-control" bind="value3-bind">
                        <xf:label ref="$form-resources/value3/label"/>
                        <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/value3/hint"/>
                        <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                    </xf:input>
                </xh:td>
            </xh:tr>
            <xh:tr class="fr-grid-tr xforms-repeat-selected-item-1">
                <xh:td class="fr-grid-td">
                    <xf:input id="value4-control" bind="value4-bind">
                        <xf:label ref="$form-resources/value4/label"/>
                        <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/value4/hint"/>
                        <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                    </xf:input>
                </xh:td>
                <xh:td class="fr-grid-td">
                    <xf:input id="value5-control" bind="value5-bind">
                        <xf:label ref="$form-resources/value5/label"/>
                        <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/value5/hint"/>
                        <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                    </xf:input>
                </xh:td>
                <xh:td class="fr-grid-td" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;">
                    <xf:input id="value6-control" bind="value6-bind">
                        <xf:label ref="$form-resources/value6/label"/>
                        <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/value6/hint"/>
                        <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                    </xf:input>
                </xh:td>
                <xh:td class="fr-grid-td" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;">
                    <xf:input id="value7-control" bind="value7-bind">
                        <xf:label ref="$form-resources/value7/label"/>
                        <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/value7/hint"/>
                        <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                    </xf:input>
                </xh:td>
            </xh:tr>
            <xh:tr class="fr-grid-tr xforms-repeat-selected-item-1">
                <xh:td class="fr-grid-td">
                    <xf:input id="value8-control" bind="value8-bind">
                        <xf:label ref="$form-resources/value8/label"/>
                        <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/value8/hint"/>
                        <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                    </xf:input>                                     
                </xh:td>
                <xh:td class="fr-grid-td">
                    <xf:input id="value9-control" bind="value9-bind">
                        <xf:label ref="$form-resources/value9/label"/>
                        <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/value9/hint"/>
                        <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                    </xf:input>                                     
                </xh:td>
                <xh:td class="fr-grid-td">
                    <xf:input id="value10-control" bind="value10-bind">
                        <xf:label ref="$form-resources/value10/label"/>
                        <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/value10/hint"/>
                        <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                    </xf:input>                                     
                </xh:td>                
            </xh:tr>                                
        </xf:repeat>
    </xh:tbody>
    </xh:table>
</fr:section>
```

Thanks

Roberto

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the largest hit on performance comes from the cost of running an `<xf:insert>`. So I'd recommend you try moving this outside of your loop, this to only have 1 `<xf:insert>`. So just after the `<xf:delete>`, you would do:

```
<xf:insert
    context="instance('fr-form-instance')//nodes"
    ref="*"
    origin="
        for $i in (1 to count(instance('fr-service-response-instance')//*:node))
        return instance('nodes-template')"/>
```

Then inside the `<xf:action iterate="…">`, you would remove the call to `<xf:insert>`, and will need to change the `<xf:setvalue>` to target the "current" `nodes-iteration`, instead of the last one, with something along these lines:

```
<xf:action iterate="instance('fr-service-response-instance')//*:node">
    <xf:var name="i" value="count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1"/>
    <xf:setvalue ref="instance('fr-form-instance')//nodes-iteration[$i]/value1"
                 value="context()//*:value1"/>
    <xf:setvalue ref="instance('fr-form-instance')//nodes-iteration[$i]/value2"
                 value="context()//*:value2"/>
    <xf:setvalue ref="instance('fr-form-instance')//nodes-iteration[$i]/value3"
                 value="context()//*:value3"/>
</xf:action>
```

Comment: Hi Alessandro, I answer you.

Comment: @Roberto Meta: you posted a follow-up on my answer as another answer, which isn't how Stack Overflow works. Answers are only for answers to the original question, not follow-up discussions. So I would recommend you delete that "answer", and post a summary in a comment below.

Comment: @Roberto To your point, is the performance better with the solution I suggested, forgetting for a second that it doesn't do what you want if you keep updating the `[last()]` inside the loop? If it is better/acceptable, then we can figure how to solve that (and otherwise, I guess there is no point in trying).

Comment: No, the performance was better without updating [last()] inside loop. Using the [current()] index instead is more slow and it sets the value just on the first node.

Sorry for the wrong answer, I tried to post here that code but it was too long.

Comment: @Roberto I wasn't trying to contrast `[last()]` vs. `[context()]`, but was wondering if it runs faster with a single `xf:insert` outside of the loop. Does it? And if it does, by how much did that improve performance?

Comment: Yes, the single xf:insert outside of the loop improves considerably performace (if I run the upload without the loop). Now the problem is the set of xf:setvalue istructions inside the loop.

Comment: @Roberto OK, good! Then let's make those `xf:setvalue` work! I've updated my answer to include a snippet showing how you can do that. You'll let me know if this helps.

Comment: Ok, I try only the xf:insert with 500 elements but it spends more than 3 minutes... too much! With your updated complete solution it spends exactly 3 minutes and 56 seconds.
Maybe can be a problem related to the components types used in the repeated-grid? I have three autocomplete components and one datetime component to repeat for each xf:insert row ... can be this the issue of so much loading time?
Let me know, please, thanks.

Comment: @Roberto Indeed, this seems too long; could you put your new snippet of code in a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/), so I can double check what you're doing now?

Comment: Ok, I put my snippet here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8295c263b7855aaa053f5c0caa10c3aa

At the end there is my entire form with the import snippet you can try importing the starting 500 elements xml. I leave only the xf:insert test active for now and it spends more than 3 minutes to load all the elements.

Thank you.

Comment: @Roberto And just to confirm, what takes time is the action that runs on `xforms-submit-done` for `upload-submission`; is that correct? This is what takes 3 minutes and 56 seconds, the way it is there, without the loop doing the `xf:setvalue`?

Comment: Exactly. I think it's the xf:insert instruction.

Comment: @Roberto Thank you for the test case, and I managed to reproduce the performance issue. From what I can see in the logs, the issue doesn't come from the `xf:insert` but from all the work done because we have all those controls created. Note that 500*9 = 4500 controls. The insertion takes exactly 180 seconds on my machine, which is 180000/4500 = 40 ms per control. Agreed: this is way too much, but right now there is no easy way to avoid it if you have all those controls displayed on the page. Would it be possible for you to only show some of the rows, and maybe add paging to access other rows?

Comment: yes, pagination is the best solution if it can help to reduce the spent time, besides it can help to read all the entries in a better way. How can I achieve the pagination? Can you show me a working snippet? Thank you.

Comment: Hi Alessandro, any news?

Comment: Roberto, sorry for the delay. Unfortunately, it isn't just a matter of "adding a snippet somewhere". This would need to be implemented in [`grid.xbl`](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/form-runner/jvm/src/main/resources/xbl/orbeon/grid/grid.xbl). If you're already pretty comfortable with XPath and XForms, you could try to have a go at it. Also, I've added a +1 from you on [RFE 1739](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1739), which covers paging.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll try to have a go at it. But when do you estimate this issue will be fixed? Maybe for the next release?

Comment: At this point, adding paging isn't scheduled for 2018.1. If the organization you work for is using Orbeon Forms PE, I would encourage you or someone you work with to contact Orbeon through your support channel (Basecamp), which will help bump up the priority of this RFE.